# stochastic gradient descent

Tags: machine-learning

Hello i am reading the book the elements of statistical learning by hastie tibshirani and friedman  https://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/printings/ESLII_print10.pdf. I am stuck at the page 131 and the equation 4.42.
I dont unterstand, to calculate the parameter Beta we can build the sum as written in 4.42 but instead we are  calculate the parameter iterative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For context, we are looking at the perceptron algorithm, where we want to find $(\beta,\beta_0)$ such that:
$$
\beta,\beta_0 = \underset{\beta,\beta_0}{ \text{argmin } }
D(\beta,\beta_0) = \underset{\beta,\beta_0}{ \text{argmin } } -\sum_{i\in\mathcal{M}}
y_i\left( x_i^T\beta + \beta_0 \right)
$$
where $\mathcal{M}$ is the index set of misclassified points.
(Note that $x_i^T\beta + \beta_0<0$ for $i\in\mathcal{M}$ ).
So we can use stochastic gradient descent:
$$
(\beta,\beta_0) \leftarrow (\beta,\beta_0) + \gamma(y_ix_i,y_i)
$$
where $(y_ix_i,y_i)=\nabla D$ with learning rate $\gamma$.

Notice it is not obvious how to calculate $\tilde{\beta}=(\beta,\beta_0)$ in closed form (i.e. not iteratively). That's because *there are many $\tilde{\beta}$ that can satisfy this criterion*. Any separating plane gives $D=0$, but there can be many ways to achieve a separating plane.

Because of this, there can be no "direct calculation". Notice that random restarts of the algorithm will give different, but equally valid, results.
Thus, we are using *stochastic* gradient descent.

Using other algorithms, like least squares or LDA, can give a unique solution which you could compute non-iteratively. Maybe better is Vapnik's linear SVM, which has a unique solution, though it is often determined iteratively too, because it adds additional constraints to the perceptron problem.